# Solr index fields not showing a field

Tags: 7, entities, search

I have a field within a field collection that I need indexed. It's not showing up in the `/admin/config/search/search_api/index/solr_node_index/fields` page. I tried using [this](http://ygerasimov.com/add-custom-field-search-api-apachesolr-index) to try to add it myself, but I don't really know how to reference it. I know that the field collection is just an array of id numbers that you can reference, but I need to reference the actual field. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [apachesolr field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_field_collection) module available, which makes me think that field collection support is probably not out of the box with the [apachesolr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) stuff.

As a matter of fact, if you look at the [issue queue for the apachesolr module](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/apachesolr?categories=All) you can find this ticket #1810228 : [Process Field Collection Items](https://www.drupal.org/node/1810228). It confirms that field collections are not supported out of the box, and the comments point to the [apachesolr field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_field_collection) module, and indicate that the module may be buggy...

I'd say try it, but test your integration thouroughly. And do try both available versions (alpha and dev), and see how it goes.

Comment: I'm actually using search api, not apache solr, which is supposed to have field collections built in. I found this https://www.drupal.org/node/2429355 which is a little similar, but not quite. It seems like the fields within the field collection that are shared are not being picked up.

Comment: Did you tick the "Aggregated fields" checkbox as mentioned in https://www.drupal.org/node/2429355#comment-9677915 ? I've just tried your scenario and followed the instructions in that thread and I can see my field collection under the fields list. So double check your  "Aggregated fields" checkbox in the  "Filters" tab.

Comment: Yes, that checkbox has been checked the whole time. It seems to me that because the field is shared between that field collection and other content types, that it's hiding the one that is in the field collection and not the one that is used by content types.

Comment: If what you mean is that you have one of your fields of the field collection used again in a content type, I jsut tried that and it works fine for me. Both show in my default index node fields admin page

Comment: Have you got your field collection listed under the "ADD RELATED FIELDS" dropdown at the bottom of the admin fields page ?

Comment: Yes, all the other fields in the field collection are seen in either "add related fields" or in the actual index. This field (not in the collection) is also in the index.

Comment: are you on an up to date drupal version ? and up to date for the modules ?

Comment: if you add another field collection do you get the same problem ?

Comment: Yes, I added a test_field_collection and added the same fields to it. I can add the actually field collection to the index, but that doesn't index the fields within the field collection. I tried adding the paragraphs module, but that seemed to have the same bug.

Comment: ok, but if you put different fields in your test_field_collection ?

Comment: None of the field collections are being indexed, at all.

Comment: You say "It seems to me that because the field is shared between that field collection and other content types, it's hiding the one that is in the field collection and not the one that is used by content types.". So would avoiding field reuse be a reasonable workaround ? Beyond that I'm out of ideas.

Comment: you mentioned you tried adding the custom field in code as described in the link you posted. Can you post your code?